# Using report in global function

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to figure out how I can do a *self.report* from my function which is triggered by the end of the texture bake event.

By pressing this button, it adds my *"my_bake_bake_complete"* function to the handler of the *"object_bake_complete"*- so right after when the texture bake is finished my function runs. After adding the function to the handler, in the next line, I call the default bake, so the texture bake begins.

```
class mybake_Bake(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mb.bake_button"
    bl_label = "My Bake Button"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.app.handlers.object_bake_complete.append(my_bake_bake_complete)
        bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
   
def my_bake_bake_complete():
    self.report({'INFO'}, "Object bake complete...")
```

And this almost works without any issue, but the *self.report* part. The *"my_bake_bake_complete"* function is called correctly after the bake (I tested it with a simple `print("")` and it prints). I'm guessing the problem is with the context in the *"my_bake_bake_complete"*.

Also, there is a type error in the console:

> TypeError: my_bake_bake_complete() takes 0 positional arguments but 2
> were given

Unfortunately, I have no idea what arguments and how they should they be passed.

Comment: What is `self.report`? Clearly, it's a part of some bigger code, but taken out of context it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't think it's part of a bigger code. As far as I know, it displays messages in the  Info panel and in the console.

Comment: no, this can not by itself display a report... this need interactive operator to be reported

Comment: "I don't think it's part of a bigger code." - where did you get this code from? Did you write it yourself? Did you copy-paste it from somewhere? If you got it from chatGPT, it's pointless to post a hallucinated code, instead explain what you mean by "report", do you want to print a message into console, or do you use some debugging library.

Comment: I don't know what was the original source where I found it, but it's also used in this video for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgQ9ahMuDMw

Comment: I'd like to use it to give states about a function, like when it's finished or failed for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

like lemon said. in python the self is only defined in a class. but in your case you just have a global function. You can only run the report function from inside an Operator. Now the problem is, when you start the operator from the function, the operator has no context.
A way to get this message to display after a bake has finished, is to initialize the bake yourself and then you have full control. Seems like your doing this anyways ("Auto bake:...").

```
import bpy

class BakeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.bake_operator"
    bl_label = "Bake Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.bake()
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Auto Bake: Object bake complete...")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class BakePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Bake Operator"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_bake_operator"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Bake'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.bake_operator")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(BakeOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(BakePanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BakeOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(BakePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note you have to init everything from a UI button press, for the report function to work. This wouldn't report anything:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.object.bake_operator()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the original post. I tried to give a more detailed and better explanation about how and what I'd like to do exactly. I hope its more clear now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Python noob, so I'm probably explaining things wrong, but perhaps my uneducated explanations will be more understandable?
There are only three `report()` methods I know in BPY:

- [bpy.types.Macro.report](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Macro.html#bpy.types.Macro.report)
- [bpy.types.Operator.report](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report)
- [bpy.types.RenderEngine.report](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html#bpy.types.RenderEngine.report)

The way I understand it:

You are making an operator, so it would make sense to make use of [bpy.types.Operator.report](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.report). It is part of the operator type, so you must call it from within your operator's class. Hence, in the tutorial, it is indented inside the class and is preceded by `self.` ([here's why you need self](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722353/10705720)).
For this to be run at the end of your operator, all you need is to put it at the end of your `execute` function, just before `return`.

So, in other words, make a nice operator class with `report` at the end, a nice UI panel class to make you panel and button that allows you to run the operator, and finally the register/unregister functions to use all that in Blender.
Which is exactly [soerensc_'s answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290541/53447).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @L0Lock! Unfortunately, putting the report at the end of the execute or after the bake line doesn't solve the problem. I think bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT') is run on a different thread or something, hence the report would appear instantly, not only after the bake. It might work without the 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' parameter, but then I would lose the progress bar for the baking, which I'd like to keep, and the UI would also be frozen until the bake finishes, so it's not an ideal solution. Regarding the panel and the (un)register parts, they are fortunately 'done'